# What difference between AES_128_GCM and AES_128 and AES_128_CBC ciphers?

Tags: encryption, tls, hash, aes

I encountered `AES_128_GCM` cipher, tried to find it in specifications of `TLS1.2` and nothing, any mention. Could some one explain the difference between `AES_128`, documented `AES_128_CBC` and this new kid `AES_128_GCM` ?

Also, have `.NET  System.Security.Cryptography` any `AES_128_GCM` build in classes ? I don't see no one.

Comment: It's simple: `AES block cipher` (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with 128 bit key used in `Galois/Counter Mode` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode).

Comment: The GCM *ciphersuites* for TLS1.2 are in RFCs 5288 and 5289, which are the first two hits for google "TLS GCM ciphersuites". But for the algorithm they reference SP800-38D which is rather formal and I agree wikipedia is a better starting point.

Answer (score 15):

**AES 128** is the [AES block cipher](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), using a key size of 128 bits. It doesn't specify the block mode in which it is being used.

**AES 128 CBC** is the same cipher as before, in this case using it in [Cipher Block Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29). (Complete description of CBC in the [NIST recommendation](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf)).
[image: CBC mode]

**AES 128 GCM** is again the same cipher, used in Galois Counter Mode. It is important to note that GCM mode also provides authentication of the data (it is a mode for "Authenticated Encryption").

If you want to get a general idea of the different block cipher modes, you can check the entry in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). For a more detailed explanation, you can check the website of NIST with all the proposed modes for block ciphers: [NIST Block Cipher Modes](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/modes_development.html)

Comment: What is the default cipher mode?  What is the "cipher mode" if cipher is mentioned as AWS_128?   Is "CBC" the default cipher mode? Does "AES_128" implicitly means "AES_128_CBC"?   Is "AES_128_GCM" stronger than "AES_128"?